# Android: Custom Adapter not sorting list view

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have one listview which adds correctly the Strings however after I sort the list cell and call notify, the adpater don't sort too. This seems reasonable since im not linking list cell and the adapter. So how to do that?

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.viewListViewUsuarios);
List<TextView> listCell = new ArrayList<TextView>();

//(get all TextView and put them on listCell)...

private void reorderArray() {

        Collections.sort(listCell, new Comparator<TextView>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(TextView t1, TextView t2) {
                return t1.getText().toString().compareToIgnoreCase(t2.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        CustomAdapter myCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);

    }
}
```

And this is my Custom Adapter class

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listCell.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.usuarios_aguardando_cell, null);

        TextView item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtUsuariosAguardandoText);
        Button btnInv = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnUsuariosAguardandoViewInvisible);

        TextView cell = listCell.get(i);
        item.setText(cell.getText());
        return view;
    }

}
```

PS: Ive searched for other links similar to these but none were effective.

Comment: did you try to use notifyDataSetChanged after sorting the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sorting the text views, you should have an `ArrayList<DataObject>` which backs your adapter.  The `DataObject`s can be custom objects or Strings if that's all you need.  Here's an example

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  private List<DataObject> dataObjects;

  public CustomAdapter(List<DataObject> dataObjects) {
    this.dataObjects = dataObjects;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return dataObjects.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int i) {
    return dataObjects.get(i);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int i) {
    return dataObjects.get(i).getId();
  }

  @Override
  public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    DataObject dataObject = dataObjects.get(i);
    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.usuarios_aguardando_cell, null);

    TextView item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtUsuariosAguardandoText);
    Button btnInv = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnUsuariosAguardandoViewInvisible);

    item.setText(dataObject.getText);
    return view;
  }

}
```

As you can see we have a list of objects we are displaying in the adapter

Answer (score 0):

`Textview` content may change when you get it.
Please get all `TextView`'s content and put them on `listCell`.

```
List<CharSequence> listCell = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
```